# Prometheus does not store more than 30 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, monitoring

I have a Prometheus server that is using 'remote_write:' in AWS ams prometheus. It is currently working. However, I can only view the data for 30 days. From what I've read, they must be retained for 150 days.

Does anyone know how to configure to retain for more than 30 days? And if my setup needs something.

This is my setup for remote write:

```
    remoteWrite:
        - url: https://aps-workspaces.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/workspaces/xx-xxxx-xxxx/api/v1/remote_write
          sigv4:
            region: us-east-1
          queue_config:
            max_samples_per_send: 1000
            max_shards: 200
            capacity: 2500
```

Retain data beyond 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the maximum time range of any PromQL query in AMP is set by default to 32 days, even if you have 150 days of retention.
Unfortunately this quota is not adjustable see "Query time range in days" in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/prometheus-service.html

It would be good to open a ticket to AWS for requesting this param to be extensible.